# Change a Column to Primary Key in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ddl

I have a table in my app

> CREATE TABLE VisitDetails (VisitId INTEGER, UserId TEXT, VisitNumber
>   TEXT, JobId INTEGER, JobNumber TEXT, StatusId INTEGER, Status TEXT,
>   SignatureRequired BOOL, StatusDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   ,StartDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, EndDate TIMESTAMP
>   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, IsPPMJob BOOL)

and it was working fine but now I need to alter this table to make already existing column 'VisitId'  to become the primary key. Can somebody help me please? It might work by adding Unique constraint to VisitId column of the table but I am trying to put some efficient solution !

Answer (score 1):

You can't change SQLite tables field's primary key once the table is created,
Possible solution is,

- Create new table with desired primary key
- Copy all data
- Drop old table

Here is the documentation link : https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. So can I add a new column as Unique? The purpose is to stop adding duplicate entries so I'll put the same visit id in that column but only the name would be different. So can I make a new column as Unique in already existing table?

Comment: you can do one thing, before insert any record into table first check if the visitId record exist in database or not, it record exist then update the record otherwise insert new record.

Comment: I have that check placed already like if VisitId exists then delete the older data and insert new entry but sometimes it just add duplicate entry at the same time. So technically it should have deleted the first entry.

Comment: You could also just make a unique index on an existing column.

Comment: As @Shawn suggest use composite key like, VisitId & UserId (combination of the two column) add as new column.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn it seems like worked fine for few of the times